# Getting the last n elements of a series by group?

Tags: pandas, data-manipulation

df:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'tic': ['B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B','B', 'C', 'A', 'A'],
                    'em': [10, 5, np.nan, 5, np.nan, np.nan, 12, np.nan, 12, 7, 
                          5, np.nan],
                    'C':[1,4,np.nan,2, 7, np.nan, 7, 9,7, np.nan, 7, 9]}
                    )

d.set_index(['tic'], inplace=True, drop=False)
d.sort_index(level=0, inplace=True)
```

If `d['em'][-3:]` does get me the last 3 elements of column `em`, why doesn't `d['em'][-3:].groupby(level=0)` get me the last 3, by group?

Also, why `d['em'][-3:].groupby('tic')` would give:

`KeyError: 'tic'` ?

I thought `level=0` and `'tic'` could both be used in this case, based on:

```
In[40]: d.index.names
Out[40]: FrozenList(['tic', 'None'])
```

Comment: Consider adding sample data to make your example easier to follow.

Comment: Just added sample data

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with function [`GroupBy.tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html), last for `DataFrame` [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) column `level_1`:

```
print (d.groupby(level='tic')['em'].tail(3))
tic            
A    1971-09-30    12.0
     1972-09-30     5.0
     1972-12-31     NaN
B    1970-03-31    10.0
     1971-12-31     NaN
     1972-03-31    12.0
C    1970-06-30     5.0
     1971-03-31     NaN
     1972-06-30     7.0
Name: em, dtype: float64

d1 = d.groupby(level='tic')['em'].tail(3).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'date'})
print (d1)
  tic       date    em
0   A 1971-09-30  12.0
1   A 1972-09-30   5.0
2   A 1972-12-31   NaN
3   B 1970-03-31  10.0
4   B 1971-12-31   NaN
5   B 1972-03-31  12.0
6   C 1970-06-30   5.0
7   C 1971-03-31   NaN
8   C 1972-06-30   7.0
```